# SSH hang at the end of one command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Below command is not coming out :

```
ssh -x -l root  asr-bng-ubuntu "/usr/local/sbin/radiusd"
```

But process is getting started when i checked in console.
Able to execute same command(/usr/local/sbin/radiusd) in console with no issues
Also other commands are getting executed through ssh ( like ssh -x -l root  asr-bng-ubuntu "ls")

The debug output from -vvv is this:

```
root@asr-bng-ubuntu's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 55 padlen 9 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: /usr/local/sbin/radiusd
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 0
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0  ------>Hangs here
```

Comment: what happens if you drop the `-x` from that line ? Does it change behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

Your command works correctly, ssh is waiting for the termination of the command to close the connection.

Look at [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/36419/using-ssh-to-remotely-start-a-process). And try the following:

```
ssh -x -l root server "/usr/local/sbin/radiusd &"
```

Comment: Same ssh remote command works for diff machine.Wondering how that works ? Also same command (/usr/local/sbin/radiusd) works without any delay on console

Comment: If you have different results for different machines, you may want to try and unify the environment each daemon runs in at least for the sake of troubleshooting. If you use Centos/RHEL/Fedora, you may want to use `/sbin/service radius start`.
Otherwise you can try to embed the call to the daemon in a script in which you could dump the environment (`env >> /path/to/log/myscript.log`)